# How to sort the date in dd-mm-yyyy format in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

Suggest way to store and sort in c++.

input:

```
01-02-2022
15-01-2022
20-10-2021
25-12-2022
```

Comment: What are you sorting exactly? Is it strings? Some custom date class? Something from `<chrono>`? You don't provide nearly enough information.

Comment: so apologize for what happened. Is it possible if I stores with string, I didn't custom date class. Can you advice what I should to do. Thank you

Comment: And it looks like the format is `dd-mm-yyyy`? Is that correct? You'd be better off with a custom date class or something from `<chrono>`. Because as strings, you'll have to tokenize it and then sort by each field from right to left. It just sounds messy.

Comment: Should I change the format or way to store or both?

Comment: Obviously you can't sort it as a string without extra work unless you want ordering by day. Note: No sane programmer stores dates like this. They might display the date in this format, but internally they'll use a much easier-to-wrangle data type (I reiterate the recommendation to look at chrono) or format (YYYY-MM-DD). To deal with what you have, you are forced to translate (even if only temporarily) into a better type or format and sort that instead.

Comment: If format is YYYY-MM-DD, how to store and sort?

Comment: Howard Hinnant (and friends at this point) provided [a whole library of tools](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) to handle dates and times. This library, more or less, has been included in C++20.

Comment: With YYYY-MM-DD, you can use standard alpha-numeric string sorting tools. `std::sort` will process an array or other container with no extra effort on your part (other than specifying descending order if that's what you need). Mind you, in another 7950-or-so years you'll need to deal with the Y10K problem.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I will try that way. If I have some question. Can I ask you here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the dates represented as strings, you will have to parse the strings to order the dates chronologically. You can do this in-flight, if you don't need the parsed dates, or you can first parse all dates and then operate on the parsed data.

I'll show an example that does parsing in-flight, splitting the parsing and ordering parts is an exercise for the reader.

```
void sort_dates(std::vector< std::string >& dates)
{
    std::sort(dates.begin(), dates.end(),
        [](std::string const& left, std::string const& right)
        {
            // Parse dates
            unsigned int ly, lm, ld;
            if (std::sscanf(left.c_str(), "%u-%u-%u", &ld, &lm, &ly) != 3)
                throw std::invalid_argument("Date is in invalid format: " + left);

            unsigned int ry, rm, rd;
            if (std::sscanf(right.c_str(), "%u-%u-%u", &rd, &rm, &ry) != 3)
                throw std::invalid_argument("Date is in invalid format: " + right);

            // Compare the dates chronologically: return true if left < right
            if (ly < ry)
                return true;
            else if (ly > ry)
                return false;

            if (lm < rm)
                return true;
            else if (lm > rm)
                return false;

            return ld < rd;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for explaining It must be difficult for me right now. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Slightly based off Andrey Semashev 's answer, you could parse and then store the date into a struct with a constructor taking a string input and having a less than operator for sorting, like so:

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::less
#include <string>
#include <tuple>     // for std::tie
#include <vector>

struct date
{
    unsigned int y, m, d;
    
    date(const std::string& date_str) : y(0), m(0), d(0)
    {
        if (std::sscanf(date_str.c_str(), "%u-%u-%u", &d, &m, &y) != 3)
            throw std::invalid_argument("Date is in invalid format: " + date_str);
    }
    
    friend bool operator< (const date& lhs, const date& rhs)
    {
        // Check years first, then months, then days
        return std::tie(lhs.y, lhs.m, lhs.d) < std::tie(rhs.y, rhs.m, rhs.d);
    }
};

void sort_dates(std::vector< std::string >& dates)
{
    // Requires an implicit constructor.
    // A lambda would be simple to write as an alternative.
    std::sort(dates.begin(), dates.end(), std::less<date>{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably convert the strings to `time_t`'s, and sort those. A `time_t` lets you represent the time with a single, easy to sort thing. Up to you whether to keep the original string with that `time_t`, or just convert back to the required format of string when you need it back.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

class Date {
    tm expanded;
    time_t compact;
public:
    bool operator<(Date const& other) const {
        return compact < other.compact;
    }

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Date &d) {
        is >> std::get_time(&d.expanded, "%d-%m-%Y");
        d.compact = mktime(&d.expanded);
        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Date const &d) {
        return os << std::put_time(&d.expanded, "%d-%m-%Y");
    }
};

int main() {
    std::istringstream input {
    R"(01-02-2022
    15-01-2022
    20-10-2021
    25-12-2022)"};

    std::vector<Date> dates { std::istream_iterator<Date>(input), {}};
    std::sort(dates.begin(), dates.end());
    std::copy(dates.begin(), dates.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Date>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Result:

```
20-10-2021
15-01-2022
01-02-2022
25-12-2022
```